# Por qué me sale en fechaNacimiento esta fecha 3918-06-03 cuando le he insertado Date fecha = new Date(2018, 05, 03)?

Tags: java

¿Por qué cuando imprimo la fecha de nacimiento me aparece esa fecha errónea? Si hago `fechaNacimiento.getYear()` me saca perfectamente el año.
El lenguaje es **Java**.

```
package Prueba;

import java.sql.Date;
public class Usuario {
    private String nombre, apellidos, domicilio, ciudad, dni, usuario, contrasena;
    private int telefono;
    private char bloqueado, tipo;
    private Date fechaNacimiento;

    // CONSTRUCTOR PARAMETRIZADO
    public Usuario(String nombre, String apellidos, int telefono, Date fechaNacimiento, 
            String domicilio, String ciudad, String dni, char bloqueado, String usuario,
            String contrasena, char tipo) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
        this.domicilio = domicilio;
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.bloqueado = bloqueado;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.contrasena = contrasena;
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public String getDomicilio() {
        return domicilio;
    }

    public void setDomicilio(String domicilio) {
        this.domicilio = domicilio;
    }

    public String getCiudad() {
        return ciudad;
    }

    public void setCiudad(String ciudad) {
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
    }

    public String getDni() {
        return dni;
    }

    public void setDni(String dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getContrasena() {
        return contrasena;
    }

    public void setContrasena(String contrasena) {
        this.contrasena = contrasena;
    }

    public int getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(int telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public char getBloqueado() {
        return bloqueado;
    }

    public void setBloqueado(char bloqueado) {
        this.bloqueado = bloqueado;
    }

    public char getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(char tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public Date getFechaNacimiento() {
        return fechaNacimiento;
    }

    public void setFechaNacimiento(Date fechaNacimiento) {
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nombre + "', '" + apellidos + "', '" + telefono + "', '" + fechaNacimiento + "', '"
                + domicilio + "', '" + ciudad + "', '" + dni + "', '" +
                bloqueado + "', '" + usuario + "', '" + contrasena + "', '" + tipo;
    }


}
```

La clase de prueba:

```
public class Principal {
    /*String nombre, String apellidos, int telefono, Date fechaNacimiento, 
            String domicilio, String ciudad, String dni, char bloqueado, String usuario,
            String contrasena, char tipo)*/
    static Date fecha = new Date(2018, 05, 03);
    private static Usuario nuevo = new Usuario("Samuel", "Tena", 0, fecha, "a", "a", "a", 'a', "a", "a", 'T');
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Datos del usuario: " + nuevo.toString());
    }
}
```

La salida del programa es:

```
Datos del usuario: Samuel', 'Tena', '0', '3918-06-03', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'T
```

Comment: Si te estás iniciando en Java, un consejo: no uses nunca la clase `java.util.Date`. Usa las clases del paquete `java.time.*`

Comment: La verdad esque si, estoy iniciandome en java, y estoy realizando un programa con GUI, pero lo de la fecha es algo que no me había topado hasta ahora. Gracias. Y porqué no usar la clase java.util.Date? Es curiosidad y ganas de aprender.

Comment: @SamuelTena lo que pasa es que java.util.Date ya esta en desuso u obsoleto(Deprecated) como aquí lo indica [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#setYear(int)), pero no es que no se pueda, por eso muchos sugieren como mejor práctica de programación o facilidad, utilizar **java.util.Calendar** que **java.util.Date**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando parse de [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) y el formato correspondiente **dd/MM/yyyy** , como a continuación lo muestro en tu código:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String fechaString = "03/05/2018";
Date fecha = null;

try {
    fecha = dateFormat.parse(fechaString);
    System.out.println(fecha);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Usuario nuevo = new Usuario("Samuel", "Tena", 0, fecha, "a", "a", "a", 'a', "a", "a", 'T');
```

**El resultado fue el siguiente:**

Thu May 03 00:00:00 CDT 2018

Datos del usuario: Samuel', 'Tena', '0', 'Thu May 03 00:00:00 CDT 2018', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'T

Comment: Buenas noches Darth Vader, gracias por contestar. Voy a probar lo que me has dicho, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 4):

El problema se debe a que estás utilizando el constructor [`Date(int year, int month, int day`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date-int-int-int-) de la clase [*Date*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) y este recibe tres parámetros de la siguiente forma:

- **year** - El año menos 1900; debe ser del 0 al 8099. (*Tenga en cuenta que 8099 es 9999 menos 1900.*)
- **month** - 0 al 11
- **day** - 1 al 31

> ¿Por qué cuando imprimo la fecha de nacimiento me aparece esa fecha errónea?

Porque al crear la instancia internamente se ejecuta esta línea:

```
int y = year + 1900;
```

Y al invocar el método `toString()` de esta clase para imprimirlo se suma 1900 a tu año:

```
int year = super.getYear() + 1900;
```

> Si hago `fechaNacimiento.getYear()` me saca perfectamente el año.

Esto es porque el método esta preparado para restar los 1900 que inicialmente suma al crear el objeto.

```
public int getYear() {
    return normalize().getYear() - 1900;
}
```

Este constructor se encuentra obsoleto (*Deprecated*) y se recomienda no ser utilizado.

Por otra parte debes tener en cuenta que el paquete que importas es `java.sql.Date`.

Podría interesarte echarle un vistazo a esta pregunta en Stackoverflow [java.util.Date vs java.sql.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2306051/6415698) para conocer las diferencias.

Answer (score 1):

El mayor problema es que estás usando un método obsoleto para construir la fecha.

Si lees la [documentación de la clase `Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) verás eso en la forma de constructor que estás usando:

> #### `Date​(int year, int month, int date)`
>
> Deprecated.  As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date) or
>   GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date).

Lo mismo ocurre con el método `getYear()`

> #### int    getYear​()
>
> Deprecated.  As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by
>   `Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900`.

### Soluciones:

Como indica la misma documentación, puedes usar la clase [**`Calendar`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), o bien una clase más evolucionada, que existe desde Java 8: [**`LocalDate`**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html).

Veámoslo en ejemplos:

```
 //Calendar
  Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  mCalendar.set(2018, 5, 3);
  System.out.println("Datos del usuario: " + mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

**Salida:**

```
Datos del usuario: 2018
```

---

```
  //LocalDate
  LocalDate mLocal = LocalDate.of(2018, 5, 3);
  System.out.println("Datos del usuario: " + mLocal.getYear());
```

**Salida:**

```
Datos del usuario: 2018
```